# How to fetch multiple JSONs in parallel with Eventmachine in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, eventmachine, http-request

I'm new to EM and am following this example:

```
EventMachine.run {
http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://google.com/').get :query => {'keyname' => 'value'}
http.errback { p 'Uh oh'; EM.stop }
http.callback {
    p http.response_header.status
    p http.response_header
    p http.response

    EventMachine.stop
  }
}
```

I want to do something similar.

I want to fetch "JavaScript Object Notation" (JSON) files from several different web servers, in parallel.

I cannot find the way how to store all these JSON files in a common variable, so that I can do some calculations about them afterwards, something like in every request I store the JSON in a global array.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but what's a JSONS? Multiple JSON results?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Multiple JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

You want the requests to be in parallel and to process them after all have been completed?

You can use `EventMachine::MultiRequest` from [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/). The wiki has documentation on issuing parallel requests, see "Synchronizing with Multi interface".

You should add our code to `multi.callback` and you will receive an array of requests.